# Java: Difference between macro and micro benchmarks

Tags: java, performance, testing, benchmarking

I was reading about benchmarks and came across these terms. I'm not clear as to their exact meaning. From my understanding, a micro-benchmark, benchmarks a very small functionality of the app. In Java programming, an example would be a performance of HashMap. 
Macro benchmarks are more on an application level, based on what customer requirements are. 
Following my example, a Macro benchmark would be to benchmark an Caching application.

Can anyone shed more light on this and verify whether what I have understood is right?

Comment: Thanks. If you want to put this down as an answer, i can accept it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your explanation just about covers it:

Summery provided by *Rachasatish* and taken from his [blog](https://rachasatish.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/excellent-java-performance-tuning/)<sup>1</sup>

> **Micro-benchmarks** (repeatable sections of code) can be useful but may not represent real-world behavior. Factors that can skew micro-benchmark performance include Java virtual machine warm-up time, and global code interactions.
>
> **Macro-benchmarks** (repeatable test sequences from the user point of view) test your system as actual end users will see it.

This again is taken from the following book chapter<sup>2</sup>:

- Chapter 3, "Measurement Is Everything" of "Java Platform Performance". Author Steve Wilson and Jeff Kesselman, Publisher Sun.

---

<sup>1 which is quite an exhaustive blog article (i.e. a long list with a summary of every topic) about "**Java performance tuning tips**"</sup>

<sup>2 which is where the original [link](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPMeasurement.fm.html) seemed to be pointing to</sup>